# How to Access Each Item in A Delimited String to Find its Matching Item in a List?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, replace

I have this list:

```
box = ["apple","orange","banana", "water"]
```

And this string:

```
CheckList = "1, orange | 2, apple | 3, banana | 4, milk"
```

**Note:** The string has `"|"` and `","` delimiters.  The `|` delimiters seperate each item and the `,` delimiters seperate between an item and its key (i.e. `key`,`item` `|` `key`,`item`, etc)

**Problem:**
I want to iterate through each item in the `box` list and find the corespoinding `key` in the string `CheckList`.

The output should be like this:

```
foundItems = ["2","1","3", "water"]
```

I am a begginer to text processing and programming in general, any idea how to solve this?

I tried this but it is not helping.

```
for i in CheckList.split("|"):
    for j in box:
        if i.split(",")[0] == j
```

Comment: If you dont find the key, you want the corresponding found item to be itself?

Comment: Yes, only the items that are found in the `box` list will have their corresponding keys in `foundItems`, otherwise it should keep the item in `box` that does not have a corresponding key in `CheckList`

Comment: Just for fun: a regex based approach: https://ideone.com/ZIK6a2

Answer (score 2):

First, get a mapping from `CheckList`, then look up it from `box`:

```
box = ["apple","orange","banana", "water"]
CheckList = "1, orange | 2, apple | 3,banana | 4,milk"

d = dict(reversed(items.split(',')) for items in CheckList.replace(' ', '').split('|'))
foundItems = [d[x] if x in d else x for x in box]
print foundItems
```

Pay attention to the **spaces** in the string.

Comment: You're awesome! I have edited the `CheckList` to make it consistent.

Answer (score 1):

If the spaces in `CheckList` are not going to be consistent (as indeed they are not in the example you gave), I would recommend first running `CheckList = CheckList.replace(" ","")` to eliminate all spaces. Otherwise be sure to `split` using `" | "` or `", "`.

Other than that, your code should work fine. If you initialize using `foundItems = box.copy()`, then your loop can look like

```
for i in CheckList.split("|"): # or " | "
    for j in range(len(box)):
        if i.split(",")[1] == box[j]:
            foundItems[j] = i.split(",")[0]
```

Using `j in range(len(box))` instead of `j in box` means that it will be easy to access the corresponding elements of `foundItems`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it looks like you're checking the wrong index in `i.split(",")`. Python is 0-indexed, so when you reference `i.split(",")[0]`, you are checking the left side of the comma (the key in this case), when it looks like you want it to check the right side (the fruit).

Second,
make sure you are stripping whitespace when parsing strings like this. For example, the first item in CheckList is "1, orange ". When you split this on "," you get an array consisting of `["1"," orange "]`. Note the spaces before and after the string orange. If you try to compare `"orange"` with `" orange "`, you will see they are not equal. You can call `i.split(",")[1].strip()` to remove any leading and trailing whitespace.

Lastly, this function is not very efficient. When you have a for loop inside of another for loop, you are checking each element in CheckList for each element in box. This is O(n^2) complexity. This is not that big of a deal for 4 items, but if these lists were larger, the time would increase quickly. Here is how I would write this function:

```
box = ["apple","orange","banana", "water"]
CheckList = "1, orange | 2, apple | 3,banana | 4,milk"
CheckDict = {}
for i in CheckList.split("|"):
    j = i.split(",")
    CheckDict[j[1].strip()] = j[0].strip()
foundItems = []
for i in box:
    if i in CheckDict:
        foundItems.append(CheckDict[i])
    else:
        foundItems.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answers here, thought I'd offer this two-liner.

```
>>> d = {i.split(',')[1].strip():i.split(',')[0] for i in checkList.split('|')}
>>> print [d[key].strip() if key in d else key for key in box]
['2', '1', '3', 'water']
```